How calculate count of topological sorts of Directed Acyclic Graph which was generated from undirected tree?
I have a tree. Each edge in the tree is directed. The direction can be any. Some edges can be directed from the "descendant" of the tree to the "ancestor". Some edges can be directed in the other direction. So there can be several "roots", that is, unreachable vertices. It is necessary to count the number of topological sortings.
I understand that several connectivity components are obtained. It is possible to recursively calculate the values ​​for each subtree: any vertex is reachable from the root. But how to combine them to get an answer, I can not guess.
For example:
1 → 3 ← 2
↓
4

First root is 1, second is 2. First can be sorted by 2 ways, and second - by 1 way. Correct answer for the question is 5. How can I get 5 from 2 and 1? What is formula, can be used for more complex "trees" - directed acyclic graphs?

Are you trying to use the algorithm here or here? If so, the 2 and 1 are incorrect; there are 3 ways to sort the graph without the first root, 2 ways to sort the graph without the second root, and 5 = 3 + 2.
